# What if i set count bigger then a file size i am reading by read() syscall?

Tags: linux, assembly, io, nasm

I need to read regular file to memory, I don't know what size it is, but I know it's less then 4096*1024*4 bytes.

1. Can I just make a read(fd, addr, 4096*1024*4)?
2. Actually I've already made it, so my syscall read less then I expected. Is it a predictable behavior or I should look for a mistake in my code?

Comment: It is by all means predictable, and `read` will simply return the number of bytes actually read. If it returns 0, it means you've reached the end of the file. Also, 16MB is quite a lot - think about whether you really need to slurp all that in one syscall.

Comment: Yep I'm very restricted in size of my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694188/when-does-the-write-system-call-write-all-of-the-requested-buffer-versus-just 
Here said that normally write() writes count bytes to regular files, does read() works the same way? What size i can expect to be read by one syscall? In my case it was about 7k and i can't understand where this number come from.

Comment: There no limit to the amount you can read in one call, except that you need a big enough buffer and  you can't read past the end of a file.

Answer (score 0):

> There no limit to the amount you can read in one call, except that
>   you need a big enough buffer and you can't read past the end of a
>   file. –  Ross Ridge 9 mins ago

I figured it out, I'd just needed bigger buffer.